# "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000", OpenCV with C++ trying to opening an image

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, visual-studio-2022

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// Driver code
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //----- COMMAND LINE -----
    const String& filename = argv[1];
    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);

    //----- EXPLICIT WAY -----
    //const String& filename = "C:/Users/letto/OneDrive/Things/sonoio.jpg";
    //Mat image = imread(filename);


    // Error Handling
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image File "
            << "Not Found" << endl;

        // wait for any key press
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    // Show Image inside a window with
    // the name provided
    imshow("Window Name", image);

    // Wait for any keystroke
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

With the code above I'm trying to open an image.

There are two ways I'm trying to do it:

1. **COMMAND LINE**: I pass the image url as a command;
2. **EXPLICIT WAY**: I write explicitly the image url.

The second method works perfectly.
With the first method I get this exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAC1FFF551 (ucrtbased.dll) in OpenImg.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code 2022 so this is the way I'm passing the url through the command line:

[image]

Where is the error? Help me find out please, thanks!

Comment: Tactical note: never use `argv` until after consulting `argc` to ensure that it is safe to do so.

Comment: The error is a null pointer access. Take advantage of VS Code's debugger front end to help you track down exactly where the failure occurs and use the backtrace to pinpoint where the pointer became null.

Comment: Your null pointer is here: `const String& filename = argv[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set - according to the image attached - additional command line arguments to the *compiler* and not to the app you run.

To add command lines to the app, right click on the project (OpenImg) and choose Debugging -> Command Arguments.

(And, as mentioned by @user4581301, verifying that the argument exists by checking args would've showed that accessing argv[1] would've been out of bounds. Its a good habit to learn.)

Comment: And also consult `argc` before using `argv`. A simple `if (argc >=2)` to confirm that there was an `argv[1]` would have pointed out where the problem was (though not the solution) immediately.